# How to "clear" a position relative?

Tags: css, position

I want to reach the **left: 0** of the body but I'm inside a position relative.
Have some way to do this without change the container class?

I'm looking for something like **clear: both** of floating objects.

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="absolute">Content</div>
</div>
```

style:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    left: 100px; /*or any other value*/
}

.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: If you append the item back to the body, you will reach `body:0`.  Otherwise the positioning will always be relative to `.container`.  Depending on how `.container` is set up, you may be able to use a negative left position, but I would highly recommend against this.

Comment: One *fast-way* to resolve this is using the following trick: `left: -100px` at `.absolute`, but I think that doesn't make sense (at least for me). But think with me, Leo, why do you want to "absolute" something on the screen within a relative layer?

Comment: I can't use left:-100px, and unfortunately I can't go out of the container.

Comment: Ok, I'm confused. Do you want to stay at the extreme left of the container, right?

Comment: I can't put my object outside the .container but I need reach the left:0 of the body and I can't change the .container class.

Comment: To me it seems a code issue because if you want to keep a layer outside of another, basically and literally you just need to keep it outside. By the way, one thing that you can do is to force the left positioning again, but now with `margin-left: -100px`. If this doesn't work, then you *can/should* use a little of JavaScript.

Comment: Is this an interview question or something? Every time someone suggests something, you add "no, I can't use that particular solution". That reeks of a test, a challenge...

Comment: If you could change the .container css, than make it `position: static` and use margin or padding to shift over.

Answer (score 6):

What you're asking for violates the intended usage of absolutely-positioned elements within a relative containing block.  The [CSS2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#comp-abspos) says:

> Although the parent outer box is not actually offset, setting its 'position' property to 'relative' means that its box may serve as the containing block for positioned descendants.

Any way to do what you're asking is a hack, and you should reconsider either (a) why you need the hierarchy to be as it is, or (b) why you need the containing block to be relatively-positioned.

Comment: I really don't believe in a easy solution, I asked waiting for a magician hack. I'll leave the question open to see if something comes up. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Jonathan is right. For instance if you only need to move .container 100px to the right, there are many ways to do that without positioning it!

Comment: This is just an example.

Comment: @Leo Okay.  I still advocate (to anyone reading this question) avoiding any hack that may get posted in the future... it's much better for readability and maintainability of your code to structure the DOM appropriately than to use hacks and workarounds to get the desired layout.

Comment: Yes. @Leo even if you can't change the HTML, you can still use a little Javascript to yank the inner div out of its container and put it alongside it in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    left: 100px; /*or any other value*/
    overflow: visible
}

.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I was able to solve this problem was using the keyword "initial". This restores any property to it`s default value.

```css
#yourElement {
  position:initial;
}
```

For more information, please, refer to : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_initial.asp
and  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I didn't like the answer "don't use it, it's bad", because I find it useful to sometimes use these "position" properties.

Although I do understand the argument, that a "position: relative" element might contain other elements depending on the container's property. But then, maybe, this "overload" of the meaning "relatively positioned" should rather be diversified in the specification. Because I don't want to position my regarding element in an absolute way, but relative to its container - which I can't do other than using this relative positioning (can I?).

So I found this solution.

Usually, I define breakpoints as "size XY down", like this:

```
@wide-screen-down: ~'(max-width:1199px)';
@desktop-down: ~'(max-width:991px)';
@tablet-down: ~'(max-width:767px)';
```

etc.

Which is fine, usually, but in this case, I just didn't want an element to be positioned relative when on phone size. So I defined one extra breakpoint:

```
@phone-up: ~'(min-width:481px)';
```

So, the "position: relative" is only set on a certain min-width! Instead of setting it and later trying to unset it - which didn't work for me with any of the keywords (unset, initial, inherit).

This doesn't really answer the OP's question - resp. the answer is, there is no way to unset the "position: relative" setting, at least in Chrome 86 on Linux. The workaround is the above, in case you can tie this property to a screen size.